# Rectangle Tool - Colored on screen, but clear/transparent when printed in pdf?

Tags: pdf, adobe-indesign

I have designed a multi-page report with wide, colored borders (roughly 1 inch on the left margin and 1 inch on the top margin) - and the left margin is a dark blue and the top margin is a light blue. The design looks fantastic on screen, and I export it to pdf for distribution to clients. Again, on screen, it looks great. The problem is that if a client wants to print it in black & white, it just wastes a ton of ink printing all those margin-boxes in gray scale. Is there a way to specify that these rectangle tool boxes used for styling are preserved on screen, but are clear/transparent if printed? (in pdf format)

Thanks!

Comment: This question is considered off-topic since it does not relate to programming or scripting. You would be better off asking on the [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you have such a requirement that you want to print grayscale but the content has to have color. InDesign is a tool with good production workflow reputation. One layout won't solve your problem. Create an alternate layout from pages panel with the same document setup and modify it to meet the other requirements. 
This is one of the workarounds that can solve your problem. For a more detailed help, try Adobe forums or join their prerelease program( which I believe is quite easy to join). The folks at Adobe will be able to give a solution if one exists.